# SQL Server : how do you get Last Months Value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

This is common problem where I want to include summary columns at the end of my detail (specifically max value for the period). I am not supposing the way I suggesting is the only the way as I could I guess alternatively have a summary row. Anyhow assume the following dataset (say ContractExpenses):

```
Contract | Period | Amount
---------+--------+-------
A        | 201803 |  50.00
A        | 201803 | 100.00
A        | 201802 |  30.00
A        | 201802 |  40.00
A        | 201801 |   5.00
B        | 201803 |  60.00
C        | 201802 |   6.00
```

My parameter is `Period`, say 201803.

Result set I want is:

```
Contract | Period | Amount | MaxAmountForThisMonth | MaxAmountForLastMonth
---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------
A        | 201803 |  50.00 |          100.00       |       40.00
A        | 201803 | 100.00 |          100.00       |       40.00
B        | 201303 |  60.00 |           60.00       |
```

This might seem an obvious thing to do at first however; consider first the fact I using a multi nested CTE to get my dataset (`ContractExpenses`) so if I have to reuse it in a further nested CTE then my query already takes time. I know the smart alecs will say dump your data into a temp table first however; this is a predefined inline table valued function that I just need to update and there are certain thing you can do in a stored procedure that you can't do in a function so assume to if only to humour me that this is the only way. Besides the point I need to reuse the function for another purpose with another filter criteria, so if I have to drop the function and use a stored procedure then I have change the other process as well which I am trying to avoid.

The most simplest way of doing this I could think of assuming a temp table (for my example data below I will just use a single nested CTE) is:

```
DECLARE @Period INT = 201803

DECLARE @LastMonth DATE, @LastPeriod INT

SELECT 
    @LastMonth = DATEADD(month, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(@Period / 100, @Period % 100, 1)),  
    @LastPeriod = YEAR(@LastMonth) * 100 + MONTH(@LastMonth);

WITH CTEContract(Contract, Period, Amount) AS 
(
    SELECT 'A', 201803,  50.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 201803, 100.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 201802,  30.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 201802,  40.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 201801,   5.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 201803,  60.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 201802,   6.00
)
SELECT * 
INTO #ContractExpenses 
FROM CTEContract;

WITH CTELastMonth AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Contract, MAX(Amount) AS MaxAmountForLastMonth
    FROM 
        #ContractExpenses
    WHERE 
        Period = @LastPeriod
    GROUP BY 
        Contract
)
SELECT 
    t.*, 
    MAX(t.Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Contract) AS MaxAmountForThisMonth, 
    l.MaxAmountForLastMonth
FROM 
    #ContractExpenses t
LEFT JOIN 
    CTELastMonth l ON t.Contract = l.Contract
WHERE 
    Period = @Period

DROP TABLE #ContractExpenses
```

So is there anyway to get this working in a function i.e. I can't select into a temp table within a function and I can't use a further nested CTE as this makes my functions time to run out to an unacceptable level. I did consider using LAG but I could not figure it out.

Comment: Can you clarify a few things: 1) You mean UNION ALL don't you? 2) What version of SQL Server (this matters when selecting the best windowing function) 3) When you say "function", do you mean an in-line table valued function?

Comment: Good point you might have hit the nail on the head I didn't think of using a multi-statement table valued function, add as your answer and I will tick it

Comment: No go on the multi-statement valued function I still get a "Cannot access temporary tables from within a function" error. alternatively If I insert directly into the table and do an update for the Max values my whole process is taking minutes (I stopped after 4). As a stored procedure it takes about 20 secs

Comment: Glen and @marc_s Thanks for editing as per my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution so I was forced into dropping the function. I instead created a view to create the ContractExpenses and used it multiple times and thus used my solution I provided above in a Stored Proc and similar for my other processes that need the same dataset.